# Can't execute project downloaded from Github

Tags: python, github, pycharm

I had to download a source code from Github and change some points.
This is the link of the Github project : https://github.com/xiangyue9607/BioNEV

I downloaded the source code and I oppened it with Pycharm. I had errors in the import section like shown in the figure
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on `src/bionev` and `Mark Directory as` `sources root`.